# How to check if the data entered is present in a log file in unix?

Tags: bash, datetime, unix, sed

I have a log file with the following data

```
Apr 10 16 02:07:20  Data 1
Apr 11 16 02:07:20  Data 1
May 10 16 04:11:09  Data 2
May 12 16 04:11:09  Data 2
```

I have to check if the entered data is present in my file.And if not,it should show error.I am using the following code.

```
if [ ! -d "$StartTime" ]
then
{
echo " $StartTime does not exists in the file"
exit
}
fi
```

where `"$StartTime"` stores `Apr 10 16 02:07:20` date. Where should I specify the logfilename?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may write it as below:

```
StartTime="02:08:20"
if [ `grep -c "$StartTime" *` -eq 0 ]
    then echo " $StartTime does not exist in the files"
fi
```

- `grep` to match for the search string and `-c` for count of matches
- `if` matched lines count `-eq` aka equals 0, print not matched

Comment: I am already storing `Apr 10 16 02:07:20` in `$StartTime`.  May I know why we are using `*|wc -l` -eq 0`? Will it work in GIT Bash?

Comment: @Vishwaroopa, not sure about the GIT Bash, you may try if the commands are available. Mostly they are available on flavors. You may set StartTime as you wish.

Comment: Thanks. Where can I specify my log file name? It has to check if the date in `$StartTime` i.e) `Apr 10 16 02:07:20` is present in log1.log(filename)

Comment: **note:** there is no need to pipe to `wc -l`, that is what `grep -c` is for. `:)`

Comment: @Vishwaroopa, you can replace `*` in `grep` to specific files or use `log1*` to match any file starting with `log1`

Comment: Sure, you always want to avoid `|`'s if possible because each pipe spawns a separate *subshell*. Both work, but for efficiency, always look to avoid subshells. You can run your scripts through [**shellcheck.net**](http://www.shellcheck.net/) and it will point out errors and areas of improvement.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Works fine :)

Comment: Also, grep has exit code of 0 if match is found & non zero otherwise. No need to use `[ \`grep -c \` != 0]`. See the other answer by Jürgen Hötzel.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to count the number of entries. `grep` will fail (i.e. return exit Status `1` if the searchstring is not found:

```sh
StartTime="02:07:20"
if grep -q "${StartTime}" test.log;then
    echo " $StartTime does not exist in the files"
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer